# Как оптимизировать поиск в Django

Tags: python, оптимизация, sql, postgresql, django

У меня есть приложение написанное на питоне (Django). База данных postgres. Хочу оптимизировать поиск. Мои модели:

```
class User(models.Model):
    #some fields

class UserAction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='actions')
    date = models.DateTimeField(datetime.datetime.now)
```

Запрос типа:

```
user_by_range = User.objects.filter(actions__date__range=(start, end))
```

Выполняется дико долго. Как мне оптимизировать мои модели и/или запрос?

Добавил индекс в класс активности, не помогло

```
class UserAction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='actions')
    date = models.DateTimeField(datetime.datetime.now, db_index=True)
    value = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, default=0)
```

Как указать, чтобы django добавил индекс в таблицу `User` для поля `actions`? re`models.ForeignKey` не принимает параметра `db_index`.

Предыдущий запрос не совсем корректен. На самом деле я делаю такой запрос:

```
user_by_range = User.objects.filter(actions__date__range=(start, end)).annotate(v_sum=Sum('value')).order_by('-v_sum').distinct()
```

Как я понял, тормоза идут из за `annotate(v_sum=Sum('value'))`. Пытаясь это оптимизировать делаю так:

```
 user_by_range = User.objects.filter(actions__in=UserAction.objects.filter(date__range=(start, end))).annotate(v_sum=Sum('value')).order_by('-v_sum').distinct()
```

В итоге имею тоже самое. Но есть идея - возможно ли на стадии

```
UserAction.objects.filter(date__range=(start, end))
```

посчитать сумму для каждого пользователя, а потом взять, к примеру, только 20  первых id пользователей  и по ним выбарть из таблички `User`. Приведет ли это к оптимизации? Как посчитать сумму `value` для одинаковых id пользователя в табл. `UserAction`?

`distinct` - не помеха. С ним и без него работает одинаково. Если убрать `annotate` не тормозит.

И так, я посмотрел запрос cгенерированный платформой Django. В запрос вставлен оператор `GROUP BY` по всем колонкам (их около 15). Я думаю в этом и есть проблема (группировать надо только по id пользователя). Как мне сделать так, чтоб `GROUP BY` был только по одной колонке?

Comment: foreign сам по себе ( должен ) индексируется

Comment: А сколько у вас записей в таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Покажите сгенерированный django - sql запрос. Создайте (вручную) в базе индекс на поле `useraction.date`.

Comment: sql запрос?

    user_by_range = User.objects.filter(actions__date__range=(start, end))
    user_by_range[0]
    from django.db import connection
    connection.queries

Comment: Не совсем понял про запрос. Зачем он вам? Мне кажеться, что дело тут в том, что я делаю запрос к таблице пользователей, а проверка идет по другой таблице. Возможно, быстрее будет обращаться напрямую к таблице активности.

Comment: Если вы говорите что тормозит - то:<br>
1. либо запрос сгенерированный django слишком ужасен<br>
2. либо ваша таблица слишком большая<br>
3. тормоза субъективны<br>
А гадать - дело не благодарное

Comment: Явно убирая `annotate` получаю ускорение. `distinct` врятли будет источником проблем.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Покажите сгенерированный django - sql запрос

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не понятна.
Попробуйте поставить пакет DJANGO DEBUG TOOLBAR.
Либо, если вам нужна только первая запись, поставить лимиты. 
Например так:

```
user_by_range = User.objects.filter(actions__date__range=(start, end))[:1]
```